# Inverse image of $\sin(\frac{1}{x})$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

How do we write $f^{-1}(]0.5,2[)$?, where $f(x)=\sin(\frac{1}{x})$

Remarks

1- I am considering the case where $f^{-1}$ is not defined as function.

2- I sketch the graph of $f(x)=\sin(\frac{1}{x})$, it contains a lot of intervals, not sure how to write them down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sin\frac{1}{x}$ takes values in the range $[-1,1]$, so $f^{-1}[0.5,2]=f^{-1}[0.5,1]$, which will be the union of several intervals,  $$f^{-1}[0.5,1]=\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb Z}[\frac{1}{\frac{5\pi}{6}+2k\pi}, \frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{6}+2k\pi}]$$

Comment: But, if we sketch $y=\sin(1/x)$ we notice that  y values will be less than 0.5 when x>1.906.. so how come you took the union of these intervals?

Comment: No,I sketched it on desmos

Comment: Have a look now, I calculated it for $\sin x$ originally. For $\sin\frac{1}{x}$, I just reciprocated each end of the interval and swapped them. Notice that when $k=0$ this gives the maximum value for $x$ in interval $\frac{6}{\pi}=1.906$ as you said